# Using EJB, ClientEJB doesn't recognize domain Object in EJB project

Tags: java, ejb

This might be a stupid error made by me but here it goes:

I have created a Enterprise Aplication Project (I'm using Eclipse Indigo) called XXEar. Then I created a EJB project called XXEJB, adding it to the EAR membership (XXEar). Also creating the XXEJBClient and XXEJBClient.jar.
This way every time I need to interact with the domain in the XXEJB I will use the interfaces defined in the XXEJBClient only needing the XXEJBClient.jar be given to other projects.
And in the end I created a dynamic web project called XXWeb.

So the thing is, in my XXWeb I have my JSP and servlets, deployed the .ear in glassfish and I can access the domain in the XXEJB, by using the interfaces in the XXEJBClient adding information to the database.
Like this:

In the XXEJBClient

```
@Local
public interface UserHandlerLocal {

public void addUser(String name, int NPC);

}
```

this works, but if i want to get a "User" object it doesn't let me giving error

```
@Local
public interface UserHandlerLocal {

public void addUser(String name, int NPC);

public User getUser(int NPC);

}
```

Is something missing in the project setup?

---

EDIT:
One thing that made this work was creating only the XXEJB without creating the XXEJBClient and XXEJBClient.jar
After writing the domain classes I created the XXEJBClient and managed to facade the main operations to the XXWeb.

Unfortunately don't know how to update the XXEJBClient.jar if I want to add new classes to the domain.

Comment: Hi, the error is that in the method [CODE]public User getUser(int NPC);[/CODE] from the UserHandlerLocal it doesnt recognize que User.class being one of the fix's is to create the User.class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if XXEJBClient.jar contains both User.class and UserHandlerLocal.class.

You need to see these two class files both on client and server side.

And both class files should be exactly the same (first compile, then copy). If for some reason you compile twice the same java file (once for server side and once for client side), then you need to add serial version id to the java class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay but was away for a while...
So i went to see inside the XXEJBClient.jar and i have the UserHandlerLocal.class. Now i have to put the User.class inside this jar?
Won't that ruin the concept of showing only the the facade to access the domain objects being them transparent?

Comment: But the UserHandlerLocal references the User in the getUser method. So the User.class should be there.

Comment: Yes but the method `public User getUser(int NPC);` gives error because it doesn't recognize the User.class.
Should i add it manually to the XXEJBClient.jar?

Comment: Ok thanks. Now the main thing is... so i don't have to add it manually in the .jar, every time i create a new class in the XXEJB, is there anything i missed when i created the Enterprise Application Project? Because that should be added automatically since i used the tutorials and i missed nothing

Comment: Yes, that should be added automatically by the deployment script. The deployment script can be an Ant build.xml, a Maven pom.xml or a development IDE specific xml.